# Issue with adding a Double to a List<double>

Tags: c#, list, csv, double

I'm getting an issue with adding a `Double` to a `List<double>` from a `CSV` file. Now I've done this before, with the exact same file, and added it to a `Double Array`. 
Here is my code that works with an `array`:

```
double[] ch1Array = new double[arraySize];

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{               
   string fileName = Path.Combine(filePath, openFileDialog1.FileName);                
   var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileName));

   while(!reader.EndOfStream)
   {
      var line = reader.ReadLine(); //Get through the column titles
      var values = line.Split(',');
      if (dataSize > 0)
      {
         try
         {
             ch1Array[dataSize] = Convert.ToDouble(values[1]);
             //etc...
```

This code works perfectly and the only thing I change is that I am not using an `Array` anymore and instead am using a `List<double>`:

```
            List<double> ch1Array = new List<double>();

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Create stream reader and open file
                string fileName = Path.Combine(mainFilePath, openFileDialog1.FileName);
                var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileName));

                int counter = 0;

                //Read document until end of stream
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine(); 
                    var values = line.Split(',');

                    try
                    {   
                        ch1Array.Add(Convert.ToDouble(values[1]));
                        //etc..
```

Now I am assuming I am using the `List` wrong (it's the first time I have used `Lists`). Once the program gets to that section (it compiles and runs fine) it tells me I have an error and that my input string was not in the correct format. But since I can use the variable `values[1]` in other contexts as a `Double` I don't know what I am doing that is throwing the error.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is the exception thrown:
[image]

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: What does values[1] happen to be at the time of the exception?

Comment: This is NOT an error with your list. It is an error in "Convert.ToDouble(values[1])". But we need more info before we can help you further... What is the value of values[1]? What is the real error msg?

Comment: The `List<>` code looks OK so it is something else. Use a debugger to verify what happens. It's probably a different file even if you're sure it's the same.

Comment: i don't even think you are adding new elements in the array example unless you are incrementing `dataSize` elsewhere and increasing the array size.

Comment: The value of `values[1]` is 3276. And `dataSize` is just a loop counter (I excluded the loop to make the code easier to read).

Comment: @GrantWinney: The reason for the combine file is because I use a default directory when opening the dialogue. This has never been an issue and the value for `values[1]` is as expected.

Comment: Sure, give me a second.

Comment: Mmmk, I've never done this before. My window says 'Running', not 'Debugging', and the stack trace window just looks empty. I am trying to learn about this but maybe someone here can help...

Comment: @DiegoNolan: Yes, `datasize` is being incremented elsewhere. That section of code works perfectly; just the bottom section of code doesn't work.

Comment: I've also just noticed the value of `values[1]` when put in a `MessageBox` has quotations around it (i.e. "3276", not just 3276). I've also tried `Parse` but no luck.

Comment: I've just included a snapshot of the `exception` thrown. My `catch` block has a `MessageBox`.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` the unconverted string right before the crash and see what it is.  It may not have only numeric characters.

Comment: @DiegoNolan: As I said I think this might be the issue. When I show the value in a `MessageBox` it has quotations around it...

Comment: There is almost certainly something wrong with the string you're passing in, and not with the List itself. From the looks of the exception it's not getting as far as the "Add"

Comment: The quotes is your issue. Get rid of them. :-)

Comment: In the `CSV` file there are no quotes. And like I said this code and file works like a charm when adding to an `Array`. So how do I get rid of the quotes? I've tried `Parse` and no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said your message box was showing the value to be "3276". This means you're trying to do `Convert.ToDouble("\"3276\"")` which will throw the exception you're getting.

Change the following line:

```
Convert.ToDouble(values[1])
```

To:

```
Convert.ToDouble(values[1].Replace("\"",""));
```

Comment: Perfect. I just dropped in this code and voila it works :). Thanks!

Comment: @tmwoods - nice that it works but this answer has very little to do with the question you asked.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I definitely feel like it answered the question. If you follow the comment conversation I laid out extra details as they were asked and this answer got right to the core of my situation. The answerer gave me precise code and it worked so he earned the correct answer mark.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not parsing the CSV file correctly.  It looks something like this:

```
"Some value","3276",Something
```

When you split on `,`, you end up with `values[1]` being `"3276"` (with the string having double quotes in it, not just `3276`), which cannot be parsed as a number. I recommend you use an existing CSV library, e.g. [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) or google for something else.

Another problem with splitting on `,` is if a value contains a comma, e.g.:

```
"Some, value","3276",Something
```

Will be split into `"Some`, `value"`, `"3276"`, and `Something`. You'd then be trying to parse `value"`, which obviously won't work. For this reason I wouldn't recommend just doing a `Replace` to remove the quotes from your number.

Comment: I wish I could mark you both as correct. Thanks for the help :)